# Magento 2: How to modify product data on observer pre cache?

Tags: magento, events, caching, magento2

My problem would be the following:

I need to modify the product data on load after the product page was cached.

Everytime I load a product I need to request some data to an api and overwrite certain product attribute, even after it was cached.

I tried intercepting these events, but the code on my observers only gets executed the first time, then it gets cached:

`catalog_product_load_after`

`catalog_controller_product_view`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to request some data to an api and overwrite certain product attribute, even after it was cached.

If I understand your correctly, there is a API which is requesting Product Data directly from your cached page.

Is it possible for this API to just Request Data from your Backend? This would not be cached and you could modify your product attributes via afterPlugins